# Aws logging in via putty or winscp in bitnami giving "server refused our key"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty, bitnami

Firstly, I was able to login into the server using the same ppk file and the same username bitnami.

All I did was I ran a command for giving permission for copying some python libraries, which I don't think changes username or something.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bitnami
```

But now suddenly its giving me this error.

things that I have tried from other answers -

I have tried restarting my instance.

I have tried using "root" or "ec2-user".

and my key and username are correct as I was able to login before. Please Help.

How to login now? can I create new key and new login username and access my files in bitnami folder? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have changed the permissions for `/home/bitnami` recursively.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bitnami
```

is the issue. Your `/home/bitnami/.ssh` directory has to be **700** and `/home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys` has to be **600**. Since they are **777** now, you are out of luck unless you have another `ssh` terminal session open. But there are ways to restore your root partition although it involves launching another instance and attaching your root partition. Search StackOverflow.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598 is this the right way ? and if I was able to rettach my volume to new instance what should I command to fix this ?

Comment: Change the permissions of `/home/bitnami/.ssh` and `/home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the attached volume. Then detach and attach it to your original instance and start it. Note: The path will be different in the attachaed volume, something like: `/mnt/.../home/bitnami`

Comment: okay thank you very much. last question should this new instance be an ec2 instance of bitnami or any other normal ec2 instance would work? sorry I am a noob in aws.

Comment: Any linux instance. Launch a `t2.micro` and fix your original root volume. You may want to snapshot the volume before modifying it.

Comment: tried it and worked like a charm. Had to do few other things like mount xvdf1 and change home permission to 700 and umount.

Comment: @helloV Please have a look over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196354/server-refused-our-key-aws question, I am stuck on this since yesterday and still no luck.